# Form unable to be added to wordpress plugin sub menu page

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, wordpress

Ok so I was able to create the sub menu page but I'm unable to get the form to be **displayed** on the sub menu page? What would be the problem? Here is the code I'm using below. Thanks!

```
    $submenuone = add_submenu_page(UR_FILE, 'Add New User', __('Add New User', UR_NAME), 'ur_create_form', 'ur_create_user', array($this, 'render_ur_user'));

    function render_ur_user() {
                if (!current_user_can('ur_create_user')) {
                    wp_die(__('Access denied.', UR_NAME));
                }
                $add_user .= $this->add_wrap(__('Add USER', UR_NAME), "<br>"--"</br>);

                $add_user .= "<form id='ur-user-form'>\n";
                $add_user .= "<p><input type='text' id='user-name' name='user-name' value='' /> ";

                $add_user .= $this->add_wrap(__('Add User', UR_NAME), "<button class='add btn-cone'>", "</button></p>");
                $add_user .= "</form>\n";
            }
```

Now for the query

```
function db_insert_new_user($input) {
            global $wpdb;

            $result = $wpdb->insert($wpdb->prefix . UR_USERTBL,
                                    array('name'    => $input->name,
                                          'surname' => $input->surname
                                    ),
                                    array('%s'),
                                    array('%s')
                                    );
            if ($this->return_result($result)){
                $input->user_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
                $this->renderuser($input);
            }
        }

function renderuser($input){
            $output = array(
                'user_id'           => $input->user_id,
                'name'  => $input->name,
                'surname' => $input->surname
            );
            $this->render_json($output);
        }
```

Can anyone tell me, why isn't my form being displayed on the sub menu page? (ALSO) Once I do get it working, how to do I submit these values to the database(mySql)? Thanks!

Comment: `render_ur_user` doesn't seem to be echoing anything.

Comment: @Becky It is, it's echoing the function render_ur_user. Do you know what's wrong, still can't figure it out

Comment: Where is it echoing it? I see you set the `$add_user` value but I don't see it output anywhere in the function being called by `add_submenu_page`.

Comment: Oh yeah, how would I do that? Is that the problem? I don't think it's echoing it anywhere, how would I do this?

Comment: In the last line of the function, just `echo($add_user);` and see if it displays anything.

Comment: Ok thank you, I'm going to try that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `add_submenu_page` calls needs to output something. The form HTML is set in the variable `$add_user` but isn't being displayed. Change the last few lines to

```
            $add_user .= "</form>\n";
            echo($add_user);
        }
```